# Skipping the download dialog in Firefox

Tags: firefox

In Firefox's options, you can either set that you want to be asked where to save every file, or you want it to be in *place your favourite directory here*, I've noticed that most of the stuff I save I put in one directory, usually something called *Downloads* (inspiring, isn't it?).

But FF still asks, and pops up with the download dialog. It is(!) by default in that directory, but I was wondering is there a way to avoid it alltogether. I.e., when I click on *Save image* or *Save page as* or whatever, that it directly just saves it - without asking for *OK*?

Anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Edit: Although I appreciate the posted answers so far, I should clarify that I'm not looking for an organizer of downloads, nor for download managers. I just need something that will *minimize the number of clicks* I have to make to get the file from the Internet to my disc.

Comment: While you're not looking for download managers, having a download manager is probably the easiest way to reduce the number of clicks. @Rook

Comment: @Sathya - Download managers are useful when there is a common criteria that engulfs the files you wish to save (all on the same page, all of .doc type, all of ... that and that criteia ...). If not, then they just become an annoyance, when saving individual files. Besides, I already use the one you mentioned.

Comment: Updated my answer for images.

Comment: I had a look in about:config, and there doesn't look to be anything like this built into FF, so you may have to go the extension route. Sathya's answer below looks pretty lightweight and acceptable to me.

Comment: See my answer at the bottom. It's the best one but I added it only in Dec 2015 so it's at the bottom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Tools > Options > Applications
2. Go to the line of the Content Type of whatever file you no longer want to bother with

   - If you want all future text files to just download, look for the line that says Text Document
   - For PDFs, look for Adobe Acrobat Document, etc.
3. Set the action to **Save File**

   - Or just set all file and content types as **Save File** and be done with it.
4. Click **OK**

Now, whenever you hit a file that is on this list and set as **Save File**, it will just download in the background. When it's done it will show a little pop-up in the lower right corner that the thing has completed its train ride to your computer.

If you come across a file type that was not in the *Applications* list section previously, you will still be prompted.

[image: opening dialog prompt]

In which case you should:

1. Select **Save File**
2. Check **Do this automatically for files like this from now on**

   - In some cases, this may be greyed out
3. Click **OK**

For future files of the same type, go back to the first set of instructions and make sure it's set.

And if you don't want to see that dialog window pop up showing the progress of file downloads:

1. Tools > Options > General
2. In the Downloads section, uncheck **Show the Downloads window when downloading a file**
3. Click **OK**

No need to download or slap on any extensions.

Comment: While the response is well formed, people who usually come here want more than average. Average was posted above. In my options, even if the file has a .rar ext and it should be done, I suppose the server sends it as unknown mime and thus the checkbox is grey. All I can do is let it prompt me or keep search for a better answer.

Answer (score 7):

Simply <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on the link and it will download to your default directory without any dialogs/prompts.

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> may be disabled on your Firefox, in which case, follow these steps:

1. Type `about:config` into the address bar, press enter. (Firefox may ask you to "promise that you're careful". Just click yes.)
2. Look for the preference `browser.altClickSave` and toggle the Value from `false` to `true`.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: the correct preference name is `browser.altClickSave`

Answer (score 6):

Setting the preference "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" to "application/octet-stream" appears to give the desired behavior for unknown MIME types: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2430485

For known MIME types, use [random♦'s solution above](https://superuser.com/a/192775).

These two approaches combined should give you the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: But does this cause any noteworthy security risks?

Answer (score 2):

The save dialog and download dialog are two completely separate things. Selecting a default save directory will not stop Firefox from asking you if you want to download a file.

You may be interested in the [Save File To](https://addons.mozilla.org/img/uploads/previews/full/40/40579.png?modified=1263031753) add-on which allows you to select a save location from the context menu, skipping the download and save dialogs altogether.

[image]

You can customize the menu so items are nested as deep as you want.

Comment: That would result in requiring even more clicks. I just want something that /either I click save, either download, either click on a link towards a file intended for download/ just saves it to a predefined place without much ado. I also don't use/have a mouse :(

Comment: I count about 2-3 clicks to save in this situation at max. You don't have to click each expanded menu, and you can make them as deeply nested as you want (if you took the time to read). You probably won't find an add-on that is 1-click save because then people would be accidentally saving everything and it would be more of a hinder than help.

Comment: You can find that addon here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-file-to/

Answer (score 2):

> I just need something that will minimize the number of clicks I have to make to get the file from the Internet to my disc.

Try the [iMacros Firefox addon](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/). You can record a so-called macro that handles the website navigation and download for you. Once you have done that, the whole process needs only *one* mouse-click or keystroke to run automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Image Toolbar addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/243/)

[image: image toolbar settings]

Comment: Looks like a winner!

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a lot of image browsing and saving, get Bazzacuda Image Saver.  You can set a save directory, and then with a single click it will, for all tabs that have just an image, save those images in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I will partially copy [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1817645/140631) here:

---

From the `about:Config` list, try

> `browser.download.useDownloadDir`  Set this to `true`.

[image: browser.download.useDownloadDir screenshot]

This finally allows the downloaded file to silently be added to the WaterFox browser download list without any `Save As` prompt.

I tried many other answers from older posts, and none of them seemed to work. I was able to get rid of the initial dialog box (Open With or Save) by getting the MIME type listed with the help of a tool [Content-Type Fixer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/content-type-fixer/).   But the Save As dialog box just kept showing up...**Which is very annoying when you are downloading a lot of known files within the browser**

And no, I did not want to use download manager for these files, although those are helpful for other files.

Interestingly enough, the silent add to the download list was default behavior until about 4 months ago in WaterFox (Based on Mozilla browser).

Hope this helps someone.  It was driving me crazy and *the browser developers certainly do not make it intuitive to figure this all out.*