# How do I tell Firefox to stop asking me whether to open or save files

Tags: firefox

When I click a link to a file that Firefox cannot natively display, it gives me this dialog box:

[image: Dialog box prompting the user to either save the file or choose an application to open it with]

I *always* want to save files, not open them. I want that to happen every time and for every file type, without ever having to be prompted. How do I effect this behavior?

**Edit:** [This](https://superuser.com/q/192498/141581) is a similar question but it does not have a satisfactory answer. What I want is to *never* see this dialog box again. I want Firefox to just save every file I try to download, whether it’s a new file type or not. The answers to the other question do not provide a way to do this—they require you to go through the dialog once for every new file type.

Comment: Did you try to set checkbox "Do this automatically for files like this from now on" from your screenshot ?

Comment: @Alex Sure, but that only applies to one file type. What I want is for *every* file type to just be downloaded without having to go through this dialog.

Comment: I believe it pretty good explained in steps 3 and 4 here: https://superuser.com/a/192775/164837

Comment: @Alex That’s not what I want. Firefox’s preferences only show you the file types you’ve already encountered. What I’m asking for is to be able to control this behavior for *all* file types, *including the ones I haven’t come across yet*.

Comment: AFAIK Firefox would bring asking dialog only for registered file types specified in applications list, any other file's types will be handled by global preference "Files and applications" - "Save files to" or "Always ask where to save files". Switch it to "Save files to", edit your preference in applications list and it should do what you want

Comment: The other question asks the same thing you are asking.  The answers are the available solutions.  Asking the same question again doesn't produce different answers, and the fact that the available solutions aren't satisfactory doesn't make this a different question.